# Combination and probability problem. GMAT related.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

The Carson family will purchase three used cars. There are two models of cars available, Model A and Model B, each of which is available in four colors: blue, black, red, and green. How many different combinations of three cars can the Carsons select if all the cars are to be different colors? What is the probability of the Carson family picking 3 different colored cars, assuming they are all equally likely to be picked

So for the number of combos:

8*6*4 = 192. But since Blue, Black, Red is the same as Red, Black, Blue, I need to divide 192 by 3! = 32

Probability:
8/8 * 6/7 * 4/6 = 16/28 = 8/14 = 4/7.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct.  Maybe a better way to think of it is that you can choose the colors in ${4 \choose 3}=4$ ways, then each of the three has two choices of model, so you multiply by $2^3=8$ getting $32$

For the second, you are assuming that they will not pick the same type of car-that there are only eight cars available and they pick three at random.  You have done that calculation correctly.  I would be prone to assume there is a large number of cars and each pick is independent, basically sampling with replacement.  In that case the probability is $\frac 44 \cdot \frac 34 \cdot \frac 24 = \frac {24}{64}=\frac 38$.  The distinction is an English question, not a mathematical one.

Answer (score 0):

The first is correct, you can think of it like a series of choices.  There are 8 cars to chose from originally (Model A and B each in 4 colors).  Once they have picked the first car, their choices are more limited, because they cannot repeat colors, so they can choose from 6.  For the 3rd choice, they cannot pick any of the previously chosen colors, thus they are left with four.  Thus the 8*6*4=32

Another way to do the second one: you already have the top of the equation (32) because that is the number of combinations of cars if they picked ones with different colors (the desired outcome).  Probability is the desired outcome over the total number of outcomes, so now we just need to find the total number of outcomes, which is 8*8*8.
Thus our probability(32/8*8*8) simplifies out to 3/8